# Uning Autofac IOC on Business Classes

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, autofac

I am using Autofac to instance my repositories in my controllers like this

```
    private readonly IProjectRepository _projectRepository;
    private readonly IDiscountScheduleRepository _discountScheduleRepository;


    public DiscountScheduleDropdownController(IProjectRepository projectRepository, IDiscountScheduleRepository discountScheduleRepository, ISegmentRepository segmentRepository)
    {
        _projectRepository = projectRepository;
        _discountScheduleRepository = discountScheduleRepository;
    }
```

However, I am unsure of how this can be applied to my Business Class, so I am using something like this.

```
    private readonly IOptionRepository _optionRepository;

    public ItemService(IOptionRepository optionRepository)
    {
        _optionRepository = optionRepository;
    }



    public ItemService() : this(new OptionRepository())
    {

    }
```

As you can see, I am instancing the repository class manually. 
Is there a way that I can get Autofac to instance these repositories so I don't have to do it when I instance the class? Of course I will need to have a default constructor with no parameters for this to work like I want.

Thank you

Comment: Why do `ItemService` needs a parameterless constructor? which part of your code needs it?

Comment: If you need an optional dependency then you'll need to use [property injection](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2014/01/dependency-injection-property-injection.html).

Comment: I don't what to pass in instances of the repository every time I call business class (unless I need to maintain the same database context). In the case of ItemService, I created an overloaded constructor to give me a parameterless constructor....but can't I get autofac to do that for me?

Comment: Typically instead of instantiating `ItemService` yourself you would ask the Autofac container to resolve it for you: `container.Resolve<ItemService>();`. Of course all dependencies have to be properly registered first (in this case `OptionRepository`). Note that if you want the service injected in the controllers, you would also need to register the service.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating what the comments to your anwer say: you don't need the parameterless constructor. You can use exactly the same mechanism of constructor parameter automatic injection by autofac that you are showing in your controller code example, as long as the interfaces of the repositories in the service are properly registered with autofac.

With this approach you can't explicitly invoke the service constructor, but instead you have to let autofac instantiate it as a constructor parameter somewhere else. Define an interface for your service. Configure it with an autofac registration. Don't directly instantiate it, but use the service interface as a parameter in the constructor of the classes where you are using it (probably controllers), and let autofac resolve and inject it.

```
public interface IItemService
{
    IItemService(IOptionRepository optionRepository);
    ...
}

public class ItemService : IItemService 
{
    private readonly IOptionRepository _optionRepository;

    public ItemService(IOptionRepository optionRepository)
    {
        _optionRepository = optionRepository;
    }
    ...
}

public class SomeController
{
    private readonly IItemService _itemService;

    public SomeController(IItemService itemService)
    {
        _itemService = itemService;
    }
    ...
}
```

Autofac registration for the service and the repositories it uses (I didn't include lifetime scope specifications, you shoud add them):

```
module.RegisterType<ItemService>()
    .As<IItemService>();

module.RegisterType<OptionRepository>()
    .As<IOptionRepository>();
```

At the end it looks like a bubble strategy: you have to make sure that you allow autofac to automatically generate your constructor parameters by having them included in the constructor parameters of the classes that use them, and you go up through your software layers: from repositories, to services, to controllers.

Note: in addition to constructor parameter injection, autofac also offers class properties injection (known as property autowiring), but usually it is more complex to use.

As a side note: generally in model-view-controller scenarios it is considered a good practice that your controller doesn't directly use the repositories (nor knows about them). It only uses the application services. Usually it is good to keep controllers as agnostic as possible to the real implementation of the business logic internals. They just use the functionality provided by the services. The services do know about repositories and internal implementation details, but the controllers don't.

So in you controller constructor you let autofac inject the service instances it is going to use, and in the service constructor you let autofac inject the repositories. Don't define repository constructor parameters nor private members in your controller classes.